# Expose Oracle stored procedure as RestAPI

Tags: oracle, function, rest, stored-procedures

Are there any easy way to expose the existing Oracle stored procedures/functions as Rest API, without Java coding ?

Comment: Not exactly RESTful, but you can use the  [PL/SQL Gateway](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_web.htm#ADFNS1102).